# ORA-06550: line 10, column 14: PLS-00201: identifier 'UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM' must be declared

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
create table test1(item varchar2(10),level1 number(10,0),des varchar2(10));

create table test2(l_update varchar2(2000),l_item varchar2(10));


declare 

l_item varchar2(10);
l_update varchar2(2000);

cursor p1 IS
select * from TEST1;

Begin
l_update := "UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM" ;

open p1;
fetch p1 into l_item;

insert into test2 values('l_update','123');

close p1;

END;
```

I'm getting this error:

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 14:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM' must be declared

Comment: `l_update := "UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM" ; ` should be `l_update := 'UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM'; ` with single quotes. The l_item and l_update are never used. `insert into test2 values('l_update','123');` inserts static values.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you should've used single quotes and remove them (single quotes) from the `insert` statement.

But that's not all: `test1` contains 3 columns; you can't fetch 3 columns into a single `l_item` variable (you're missing two more variables); you'd rather declare a cursor variable, e.g. `l_curvar c1%rowtype;`.

Furthermore, what if `test1` contains more than a single row? You'd always fetch the first (random) one, do *something* and close the cursor.

A better/simpler option is to use a cursor `FOR` loop and let Oracle do most of the "dirty" job for you (as you don't have to declare cursor variable, open the cursor, fetch from it, (if you're in a loop - exit the loop), close the cursor).

Something like the following example.

Test tables:

```
SQL> create table test1
  2    (item varchar2(10), level1 number(10,0), des varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> create table test2
  2    (l_update varchar2(2000), l_item varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 (item, level1, des) values
  2    ('A', 1, 'Test');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test1;

ITEM           LEVEL1 DES
---------- ---------- ----------
A                   1 Test

SQL> select * from test2;

no rows selected
```

Code:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_update varchar2(2000);
  3  begin
  4    l_update := 'UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM';
  5
  6    for cur_r in (select item, level1, des from test1) loop
  7      insert into test2 (l_update, l_item) values
  8        (l_update , cur_r.item);
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test2;

L_UPDATE                                           L_ITEM
-------------------------------------------------- ----------
UPDATE TEST2 SET ITEM                              A

SQL>
```